# Cannot find org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce and mapred packages in hbase 1.2.6

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

I am trying to upgrade an existing project's hbase version which was previously 0.94.1 annd now I will upgrade to 1.2.6. In the [official website](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapred/TableMapReduceUtil.html) I can see some packages and classes such as mapreduce and mapred, but they are not available in the jars that I found. I have found hbase-common hbase-annotations and hbase-client jars. However these jars does not includes all the classes in the API. Where can I find them?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can usually work this sort of stuff out by looking at the source. Going through the different releases, you can see the following:

- 0.94.1 - https://github.com/apache/hbase/tree/2fd647d99e4aae7da71cebb9efd017eebfe0e4fb

Everything in hbase was combined in a single package.

- 1.2.6 - https://github.com/apache/hbase/tree/2f9b9e17d0522e36063bf52ecc58576243d20b3f

The code has been split into numerous packages. In this version the mapred and mapreduce code has been moved into `hbase-server` [[See here]](https://github.com/apache/hbase/tree/2f9b9e17d0522e36063bf52ecc58576243d20b3f/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapred).